# How can you measure an object in the photo

Tags: photo-editing, information-graphics, smartobject, measurement, object-styles

[image][image]
[image]

This is a bracelet I need the size of the pearl

Comment: There has to be an object in the image with known dimensions.

Comment: Three identical photos are not more useful than one. If they were shot from different directions with the same camera focal length some photogrammetric  reasoning might be possible.  The same reasoning would be possible as well if the pearls were identical i.e. you had it seen from different directions in the same image. But the focal length of the camera lens is a must for such calculations. Your photo is anonymized, there's no metadata of camera settings.

Comment: (continued) The remaining way is to know the width of one shown parts and calculate the pearl size proportionally from the width as pixels. Jewel making hobbyists and professionals may know just the shown metal parts and compare the pearls to them. They may know even the pearls. Note: every photo can be a counterfeit which needs an experienced analyzer to see it's a fake.

Comment: @Abuabapplipbleable it's worse than that. The focal length alone can't tell you anything about the real size of an object in a photograph, you'd also need much more information: the sensor size, the distance from subject to camera, the image size of the original photograph in pixels (not a crop), and you'd need to measure the size of the object in pixels too. There's a formula for this somewhere I once saw on Photography SE. The only real answer here is you can't measure the size of a real object from a photo alone. It's not possible when there are so many unknown variables.

Comment: Not true. Photogrammetry based point cloud generation algorithms search which 3D scene fits to a set of photos which are shot of the same scene from different directions and distances. The algorithm doesn't know the size of the pixel. It assumes the camera focus settings and the focal length are the same and it knows the focal length. The pearls are  problematic here because there's very little details on them so it's difficult to find corresponding pixels between different pearls. The other pieces are easier, so a reference dimension maybe could generated of the metal parts.

Comment: @Abuabapplipbleable It is true.  I am talking of a single photo alone. It's not possible without more information.  The images in the OPs question are identical. They seem to have posted the same image three times for some reason. This isn't a set of stereoscopic images.

Comment: I wrote about  the sameness yesterday. But in one photo several pieces of identical items can be considered as several photos of a single item - only mark the corresponding points to separate empty images. Insert for ex. colored points. The longest metal parts look promising for it.